# What happened to netatalk? MacOS<>Ubuntu filesharing

Tags: macosx, file-sharing

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 18 (from 17). Sharing files with Apple Macs on the same network was a breeze with 17 (after apt-geting netatalk). But doing `sudo apt-get netatalk` just gets me `Invalid operation netatalk`.

Doing `afp://ubuntuname.local` on the Mac results in `The server may not exist or is unavailable`

I'm desperate to get by Linux box to speak to my Macs again. Can someone help? Nothing has changed except I (foolishly?) upgraded both our non-Macs to Ububntu 18.

Any suggestions?

If you want to help with two users on one Ubuntu machine sharing a local folder, please look for my other post.

Comment: Also note that you can use the SMB protocol to share files with Macs.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get netatalk
```

is an invalid command. It is

```
sudo apt-get install netatalk
```

or the newer...

```
sudo apt install netatalk
```

It is part of [universe](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/netatalk) so available for 18.04.

Comment: Ah! Stupid me. Many thanks for your help - and patience.

Comment: It's invalid since `apt` or `apt-get` needs to accept arguments before passing the package name. You can't swap their position; `apt netatalk install` is invalid while `apt install netatalk` is valid.